# Composition in explicit substitutions

Tags: lambda-calculus, term-rewriting-systems

In the classical λσ calculus of explicit substitutions, there is the following rewrite rule:

```
(a[s])[t]  ==>  a[s ∘ t]
```

where `a[s]` denotes the application of substitution `s` to term `a`.

This seems backward/counterintuitive to me: if we consider substitutions as sorts of *functions*, then `(a[s])[t]` can be thought of as `t(s(a))`, which we could write as `(t ∘ s)(a)` aka `a[t ∘ s]` and not `a[s ∘ t]`.

What is the reasoning behind this notation?

Comment: Do you mind giving the reference from where you're getting this notation?

Comment: The reference is in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substitutions form a monoid and they [act on terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_action). We have a choice of writing them as either *left* or *right* actions. [Sometime in the previous millenium someone decided they act on the right](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-54.pdf) (page 5). A right action should satisfy $a [s \circ t] = (a[s])[t]$, so it makes sense to define the operation $\circ$ that conforms to action on the right. That's all.

You could do entirely the same thing with functions and write them as $x \mathbin{//} f$ (as Mathematica does) in which case you would be seriously tempted to define $x \mathbin{//} (f \circ g) = (x \mathbin{//} f) \mathbin{//} g$. In essence you'd move from the category of sets to its opposite.

Comment: Ha!  And here I was thinking that `f∘g` always means "apply g and then apply f".  I guess it's the first time I see this composition notation used on what you call "right actions" (which I tend to think as postfix operations).  Thanks.